# Wrong solution set in textbook, quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, quadratics

So we have an the equation $\frac{2}{3}t^2+\frac{4}{3}t=\frac 15$, when you finish solving the equation you get $t = \frac{-10 + \sqrt{130}}{10} $ and $\frac{-10 - \sqrt{130}}{10}$.

The text book seems to think the solution  it $\frac{10 + \sqrt{130}}{10}$ and $\frac{10 - \sqrt{130}}{10}$.
 
I've tried checking other sources to verify my answer and just want to be doubly sure that I have the right solution, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac23t^2$ etc. or $\frac{2}{3t^2}$ etc.? I suspect you mean the first

Comment: You can check that the sum of the roots has to be $-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the both sides of
$$\frac{2}{3}t^2+\frac 43t=\frac 15$$
by $15$ gives us
$$10t^2+20t=3\Rightarrow 10t^2+20t-3=0\Rightarrow t=\frac{-10\pm\sqrt{130}}{10}.$$

Here, note that
$$ax^2+\color{red}{2}bx+c=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-ac}}{a}.$$

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but the variable is squared then multiplied to the entire fraction like so: (2/3)t^2. I didn't consider how that would be interpreted.

Comment: @takooro: OK. I added some.